# Problem with undefined method `invoices' Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I just started using Rails and I'm stuck. I cannot understand why I'm getting this error:

This is the class `InnkeeperBillingInformation`:

```
class InnkeeperBillingInformation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :company_name,
            :address, :municipality, :province, :country,
            :zip_code, :tax_code, :vat, :email, :phone_number,
            presence: true

  after_create :generate_invoice

  private

  def generate_invoice
    subscription = user.innkeeper_subscription
    subscription.invoices.create(number: generate_invoice_name(user), amount: subscription.type.price)
  end

  def generate_invoice_name(user)
    month = Time.now.strftime("%B")
    "Abbonamento: #{user.subscription_type} - #{month} #{Time.now.year}"
  end
end
```

This is the controller:

```
  def create

    @innkeeper_billing_information = InnkeeperBillingInformation.new innkeeper_billing_information_params

    if @innkeeper_billing_information.save

      redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "Dati di fatturazione salvati con successo!"

    else

      redirect_to({ action: :index }, notice: "Non è stato possibile completare la richiesta.")

    end

  end
```

Class NullInnkeeperSubscription:

```
class NullInnkeeperSubscription
  def id
    nil
  end

  def active?
    false
  end

  def empty_array
    []
  end

  def type_name
    "Nessuno"
  end

  %w(eateries menu_sections menus dishes invitations innkeeper_subscription_managers).each do |method|
    alias_method method, "empty_array"
  end
end
```

Class User.rb:

```
  def innkeeper_subscription
    innkeeper_subscriptions.detect(&:active?) || NullInnkeeperSubscription.new
  end
```

This is the Stack trace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `invoices' for #<NullInnkeeperSubscription:0x00007fc42ebf3930>:
  app/models/innkeeper_billing_information.rb:15:in `generate_invoice'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:207:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_create_callbacks'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:68:in `_create_record'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:548:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:129:in `save'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
  bullet (5.5.0) lib/bullet/active_record5.rb:5:in `save'
  app/controllers/dashboard/innkeeper_billing_informations_controller.rb:16:in `create'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/route_translator-9d3350d9574c/lib/route_translator/extensions/action_controller.rb:27:in `set_locale_from_url'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:285:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `block in around'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
  searchkick (2.3.0) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
  actionview (5.0.7.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:727:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  bullet (5.5.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  activerecord (5.0.7.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:553:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
   () var/lib/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems/better_errors-707ffcf284d8/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  request_store (1.3.2) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.7.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:23:in `_call'
  rack-livereload (0.3.16) lib/rack/livereload.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.7.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.4.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:81:in `call'
  railties (5.0.7.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:226:in `call'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.7.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The methods are there but I don't understand why it gives me this error

Comment: Can you share your stacktrace that would make it easy to help you here. Also what does `user.innkeeper_subscription` return ?

Comment: I added the stack trace and what the innkeeper_subscriptio method returns

Comment: How is your class `NullInnkeeperSubscription` defined? That seems to be where the problem is. `innkeeper_subscriptions.detect(&:active?)` seems to be `nil` or `false`.

Comment: I added the NullInnkeeperSubscription class